# Why CDN link from Freecodecamp throws error in Codesandbox React template?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to include CDN link into index.html file in React app.

Below the code, this is what I tried the last so far. Still logs the error:

*Could not fetch dependencies, please try again in a couple seconds: (intermediate value)(...).then(...).finally is not a function*

```
<body>
    <!-- <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript> -->
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"
    ></script>
  </body>
```

Here is the link to **codesandbox**: https://codesandbox.io/s/randomquotemachine-uj9dy

Comment: are you sure that the error you are getting is related to the cdn link? if you could share your code in codesandbox, it could shed some light...

Comment: @bentz123 yes sure, here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/randomquotemachine-uj9dy

Comment: You are using the wrong promise library probably, because `finally` doesn't exist as method on regular promises. (Some libraries like Q have it.)

Comment: @CherryDT is there a way to switch to another library then? I just created a project and it throws error only when I add this link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem you are experiencing happens specifically  in codesandbox.io, please correct me if I am wrong.

To resolve the error:

1. Remove the CDN link from the HTML body.
2. Copy the link of the CDN to the "External URL - Add Resource"
3. Refresh Project

Here is the modified project with the issue resolved:
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/randomquotemachine-forked-e2sqp?file=/public/index.html)